# CSS file class format confusion

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I spent the whole of yesterday trying to work out why bootstrap styles were not being applied in my pages and finally notices that the styles weren't even being applied. This seems to be because the styles in my css file where in the format:

```
.cms-bootstrap .col-lg-2{
...
}
```

and I was trying to apply them like this

```
<div class="col-lg-2">hello</div>
```

the site I'm working on is quite large and we have a third party company supplying the main styles, there are several other 75k style files so it took a bit of investigation to find what seems to be the cause.

I need to apply the grid styles so I can position some elements correctly on the page.

If I apply the styles like this:

```
<div class="cms-bootstrap>
<div class="col-lg-2">hello</div>
</div>
```

then all is well and the styles are applied correctly.

Can someone please explain the significance of the outer div needed? I can see the connection between the 2 classes defined in the CSS file I just don't know what they are and can't find an explanation anywhere.

Comment: `cms-bootstrap` div is probably a container div with defined width, or some pesudoelements attached to it (`:before` and `:after` with `display:table` and `content:" "` and `box-sizing `in them). You need a container to hold the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `.cms-bootstrap .col-lg-2` identifies the nested `div.

So if the child `div` is not within that specific parent then the styling rules will not be applied to it.

You should use this as reference:

> **element**  e.g. 'p'    Selects all 'p' elements
>
> **element,element** e.g. 'div, p' Selects all 'div' elements and
>   all 'p' elements
>
> **element element** e.g.    div p   Selects all
>   'p' elements inside 'div' elements
>
> **element>element**
>   e.g.  div > p Selects all 'p' elements where the parent is a 'div'
>   element
>
> **element+element** e.g. div + p Selects all 'p'
>   elements that are placed immediately after 'div' elements
>
> **element1~element2** e.g.    p ~ ul  Selects every 'ul' element that
>   are preceded by a 'p' element

Taken from [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the third party supplying your CSS has wrapped everything in the `.cms-bootstrap` class, presumably so stop Bootstrap from interfering with other styles on the site (usually the admin area).

This is an arbitrary class so there won't be any docs on it - you'll need to add the `.cms-bootstrap` class to the `body` tag to get your content to pick up the Bootstrap styles.

Comment: yes I think you're right - it's always fun finding the solution but not knowing why it was the solution ! the answers here have helped enormously :-)

Answer (score 0):

Right well firstly if a css rule is laid out like `.cms-bootstrap .col-lg-2{` that means that the far left one is the wrapper and the right one is its children.

So in order for it to affect this class it has to be a child of cms-bootstrap.

now for the cms-bootsrtrap class that actually is made for back end only styles within a cms you see it in things like respond cms & windu where they are using bootstrap to style the backend.

Comment: thanks for your answer and although it was the first and is right I thought Philips was more complete and more help to me. Thanks though :-)

Comment: No worries first answer of the morning im still sleepy eyed lol